# Is it always necessary to add all used functions within useEffect to its dependencies array?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am currently building a Tetris game on React just to practice hooks (used to develop in class components back in the day, kind of left React for a while and yesterday I decided to use it once again).

The game is working perfectly well, and it behaves as expected on each and every situation, however, there is a constant warning related to using a function within useEffect without it being a dependency.

To clarify - I have a useEffect function that all it does is call an updateFunction and is dependent just on the x and y coordinates of the moving Tetris block. The update function updates the state of the board whenever the position of the shape changes.

I know that React re-creates functions on each and every render, but giving a useCallback to the update function would cause it to be re-created endlessly (as then, the complier would ask me to make it dependent on the board state, thus each time it updates the board, it'll be forced to be re-created once again), and this causes an infinite loop of rendering.

Is it really necessary to put every function within useEffect as a dependency, even if said functions only causes a visual rendering to show the current state of the game?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to think of the effect dependencies as "correct" or not, and not try to tailor them to achieve some specific behavior. (The vast majority of the time anyway)

This means that if an effect uses a value that could possibly change, then it's declared as a dependency. Sometimes you app works fine if your dependencies are "incorrect" because elsewhere you can guarantee a value is constant. But this is more about maintaining the application than having it work currently.

Later if you change how one of the dependencies works in a refactoring, then the effect now may need to re-run and doesn't leading to strange and hard to diagnose bugs like stale values where you can't tell where they come from.

If this leads to cumbersome hooks with huge dependency arrays that infinite loop themselves, then it's an indication that logic is messy and needs to be refactored, split into multiple effects, rethink how the data flows through your hooks, etc.

It's hard to advise specifically without seeing your code. But in your case it seems like you could make the "update function" take arguments instead, which means it could then be completely static. Or if you did use `useCallback` that depends on `x,y` then it would regenerate when those change, but you probably have a lot of logic to run when those change, so that's probably expected.

---

**Summary:**

I would advise you to take the warnings of `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` seriously, and clean your code until it passes. In the long wrong, in a large and complex application, it really helps keep things clean.

There are very rare exceptions that come up when doing non standard things, but it's worth it to try your best on this before resorting to ignoring those warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You can always put whole function inside useEffect and you want get this error and problem

Answer (score 0):

Someone just asked the similar question, and my answer is there, [React won't let me use `useEffect` in a completely reasonable way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69228720/react-wont-let-me-use-useeffect-in-a-completely-reasonable-way)

The answer to your question is that, no you don't have to, if the warning doesn't bother you, and your code is still working, then move on.

Otherwise you can try to find a way to disable this linter, or ask yourself why not to meet all the dependency requirement.