# React won't let me use `useEffect` in a completely reasonable way

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I created the following helper functions because functional components in React do not have mount and unmount events. I don't care what people say; useEffect is not a an equivalent. It can be as I demonstrate below:

```
//eslint-disable-next-line
export const useMount = callback => useEffect(callback, []);

//eslint-disable-next-line
export const useUnmount = callback => useEffect(() => callback, []);
```

React does not let me do this because I am technically calling useEffect from a non-component function. I'm doing this because when I use useEffect as a mount or unmount event, it pollutes my terminal with meaningless warnings about not including something in the dependency list. I know, I should be doing this...

```
export default function MusicPlayback(...) {
    ...
    useEffect(() => stopMusic, []);
    ...
}
```

But then I get a warning about `stopMusic` not being included as a dependency. But I don't want it to be a dependency because then `useEffect` will no longer be an unmount event and `stopMusic` will be called on every render.

I know that it is eslint that is warning me and I can use `//eslint-disable-next-line` but that is too ugly to have in every single file that needs an unmount handler.

To my knowledge there is no way to have an unmount handler without using `//eslint-disable-next-line` absolutely everywhere. Is there some way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the dependency check is there for a reason, even when you think it shouldn't be there.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    stopMusic()
    ...
  }, [stopMusic, ...])
```

Let's talk about `stopMusic`, suppose this is a global function from another third party. If the instance never changes, then you should fire it as a dependency, since it won't hurt.

And if the `stopMusic` instance does change, then you need to ask yourself why you don't want to put it as a dependency, because it might be accidentally calling an old `stopMusic`.

Now, suppose you are good with all these and still don't want it to be wired with `stopMusic`, then consider use a ref.

```
  const ref = useRef({ stopMusic })

  useEffect(() => ref.current.stopMusic(), [ref])
```

Either way you get the point, it has to depend on something, maybe your business logic doesn't want to. But technically as long as you need to invoke something which isn't part of the `useEffect`, it needs to be a dependency. Otherwise from the `useEffect` perspective, it's an out-of-sync issue. The point of ref (or any object) is to get into this out-of-sync deliberately.

*Of course, if you really hate this linter rule, i believe you can disable it.*

##### NOTE

React community is proposing a way in the future to add these dependencies for you behind your back. The rational behind it is that *React* is designed to be reactive to the data in one-way train.

Comment: The problem is that the thing `useEffect` is dependent on is not `stopMusic`. It is the entity that `stopMusic` is invoking, and the function and the entity have two completely different life cycles. Read my answer below for more.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up having to do to stop the music on unmount.

```
export default function MusicPlayback(...) {
    const [playMusic, stopMusic] = useMagicalSoundHookThingy(myMusic);
    const stopMusicRef = useRef(stopMusic);
    stopMusicRef.current = stopMusic; // Gotta do this because stopMusic no longer works after render.
    ...
    useEffect(() => {
        const stopMusicInHere = stopMusicRef.current; // Doing this to avoid a warning telling me that when called the ref will probably no longer be around.
        return stopMusicInHere;
    }, [stopMusicRef]);
    ...
}
```

Using a ref like this isn't meaningful. It is just a clever hack to fool eslint. We are packaging something that changes on every render into something that doesn't. That's all we are doing.

The problem I am having is that the entity I'm interacting with is static. But the means to communicate with that entity (namely the function `stopMusic`) is transient. So the brute force means by which `useEffect` determines dependence isn't nuanced enough to really indicate whether some dependency has actually changed. Just the tiddlywinks that invoke that dependency, the functions and object created by the hooks. Perhaps this is the fault of the hook writer. Maybe the tiddlywinks should maintain the same life cycle as the entity.

I love React very much, but this is an annoyance I've had for a while, and I'm tired of people telling me that I should just include all the dependencies eslint demands as if I don't really understand what dependencies are actually involved. It is probably ideal to never have any side effects at all in a React program, and rely on a data repository pipeline like Redux to provide any context. But this is the real world and there will always be entities with disconnected lifecycles. Music playing in the background is one such entity. Such is life.

Comment: I've selected @windmaomao's answer as the correct answer because he is right in everything he says whether I like it or not.

Comment: thanks for accepting the answer, i kinda agree with you. When I started, i tend to disable this linter line a lot. You can find a global setting to disable this entirely. But you can also take this as some helper to warn you if you are about to do things wrong. If you are so sure what you are doing, just ignore this warning, or disable it. I think you should be good to go without using the dependency and `useRef` in this case.

Comment: Yeah, this lint error is often very helpful in reminding me to include dependencies that I've forgotten. So I actually appreciate it most of the time. It just gets annoying with these edge cases. I never disable warnings or linters globally. I find that doing that can create undetectable problems. Linters and warnings are there for a reason even if it isn't a completely good one. It's just they can be wrong sometimes.